# Solving system of des using method of lines - spatially discretised

Tags: python, scipy, pde

I am trying to adapt [this example using the method of lines so solve a pde](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/03/07/Transient-heat-conduction-partial-differential-equations/) for a system of des. This is not the system I am trying to solve, just an example.

How do I incorporate a second de?  I have tried modifying `odefunc` to be

```
def odefunc(u,t):
    dudt = np.zeros(X.shape)
    dvdt = np.zeros(X.shape)

    dudt[0] = 0 # constant at boundary condition
    dudt[-1] = 0

    dvdt[0] = 0
    dvdt[-1] = 0


    # for the internal nodes
    for i in range (1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = k* (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / h**2
        dvdt[i] = u[i]
    return [dudt,dvdt]
```

based on a couple of example solutions of systems of odes I found - but as I already had an array for dudt I suspect this might be my problem.  I also don't know what my initial conditions should now look like so they are the correct dimensions etc.

The error I get is
`The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.` at line `sol = odeint(odefunc, init, tspan)`

Example with a single pde

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.interactive(False) 

N = 5 # number of points to discretise
L = 1.0 # length of the rod
X = np.linspace(0,L,N)
h = L/ (N  - 1)

k = 0.02

def odefunc(u,t):
    dudt = np.zeros(X.shape)

    dudt[0] = 0 # constant at boundary condition
    dudt[-1] = 0


    # for the internal nodes
    for i in range (1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = k* (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / h**2
    return dudt

init = 150.0 * np.ones(X.shape) # initial temperature
init[0] = 100.0 # boundary condition
init[-1] = 200.0 # boundary condition

tspan = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 100)
sol = odeint(odefunc, init, tspan)

for i in range(0, len(tspan), 5):
    plt.plot(X,sol[i], label = 't={0:1.2f}'.format(tspan[i]))

# legend outside the figure
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
plt.xlabel('X position')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')

# adjust figure edges so the legend is in the figure
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.89, right = 0.77)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the odeint [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) of the ode function defines y to be a vector, but you have it defined as a list of vectors.

> Solves the initial value problem for stiff or non-stiff systems of first order odes:
>
> `dy/dt = func(y, t, ...)  [or func(t, y, ...)]`
>
> where y can be a vector.

You can simply use the `ravel` function to create a vector from a list of vectors.  Here is an example from your code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(False) 
N = 5 # number of points to discretise
L = 1.0 # length of the rod
X = np.linspace(0,L,N)
h = L/ (N  - 1)
k = 0.02
def odefunc2(y,t):
    
    u = y[:N]
    v = y[N:]
    
    dudt = np.zeros_like(u)
    dvdt = np.zeros_like(v)    

    dudt[0] = 0 # constant at boundary condition
    dudt[-1] = 0
    
    dvdt[0] = 0
    dvdt[-1] = 0
    # for the internal nodes
    for i in range (1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = k* (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / h**2
        dvdt[i] = u[i]
    return np.ravel([dudt, dvdt])

initu = 150.0 * np.ones(X.shape) # initial temperature
initu[0] = 100.0 # boundary condition
initu[-1] = 200.0 # boundary condition

initv = np.zeros(X.shape) # initial v

init = np.ravel([initu, initv])

tspan = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 100)
sol = odeint(odefunc2, init, tspan)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

for i in range(0, len(tspan)):
    ax1.plot(X, sol[i, :N], label = 't={0:1.2f}'.format(tspan[i]))
    ax2.plot(X, sol[i, N:], label = 't={0:1.2f}'.format(tspan[i]))

plt.show()
```